# Does citation refer to paper or authors?

Tags: citations, writing-style, citation-style, grammar

I imagine this question is asked before, but I could not find the answer.

This is the example sentence that got me wondering:

> Gneiting and Ranjan (2013) **generalize/generalizes** these findings and **state/states** that ...

Should I plural verbs *(generalize, state)*, as if I am referring to the authors, or should I use singular verbs *(generalizes,states)* as if I am referring to the paper itself?

Comment: Papers don't do things; people do.

Answer (score 2):

I guess there is no definitive answer, but I would use "state". From what I learned from my supervisor, the citation should not interfere with the original sentence. And the sentence is "Gneiting and Ranjan **generalize** these findings and **state** that..."
(My supervisor also disapproved of it when someone used "[XY] stated that ... ".)

Also, I can't remember ever seeing it the other way.

Just make sure that you have the same form for "generalizes" as well ;)